# How can I concatenate the output of two commands?

Tags: bash, unix

How can I concatenate the output of `pwd` and `ls` and add it to a file called f1? This is not working:

```
pwd, ls > f1
```

Comment: Do you mean _on one line_ or do you mean _in one file_?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a compound command:

```
{ pwd; ls; } > f1
```

Comment: Not going to concatenate them onto one line. If that's actually what he wanted.

Comment: I understood, that might be exactly what he wanted. It just isn't clear.

Comment: Actually, I realized what *you* meant while typing that up, and decided not to comment, but apparently I hit enter by reflex :)

Comment: Interestingly you can write `(pwd;ls)`, but cannot write `{pwd;ls;}` or `{pwd;ls}` in bash: leading space and trailing semicolon is needed - `{ pwd;ls;}`.

Comment: For historical reasons(?), the braces are not control characters, so they can neither terminate a command nor signal the end of a word.

Comment: Btw: `printf '%s\n' "$PWD" * > f1`.

Comment: I bet braces not being control characters is related with sequences in bash (`echo {1..10}`).

Comment: The POSIX shell treats braces the same way, but does not support brace expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Saves a semi-colon and 2 spaces, costs a process vs @chepner  :-)

```
(pwd;ls) > f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you looking for do something harder but file appending is a simple solution:

```
pwd >> f1
ls >> f1
```

If you prefer chepner's or Mark Setchell's answer, here's an explanation:

1. You can use subshell with parenthesis:

   ```
   ( pwd; ls; ) > f1
   ```
2. Or subcommand:

   ```
   { pwd; ls; } > f1
   ```

With subshell, parent shell won't have access to children environment. Variable aren't kept because a new orphan process is created.

And with subcommand initialized variable are kept and usable with parent.

Both have parent environment.

Reference:

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - Subshells](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)

Comment: To be equivalent to the OP's question, you would need `pwd > f1; ls >> f1` else you will append to a file if already there whereas the original overwrites any file that is originally there. Also, the point of my command was to `omit` the semi-colon and spaces - which you have re-introduced. And Mr chepner's solution is not a sub-command, it is a `compound` command - i.e. one that consists of more than one part.